# Django How to route to a js file from urlpattern

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I want to route to a js file (may be static or dynamic).

The js file has format same thing:

```
(function() {
  var img = new Image,
      url = encodeURIComponent(document.location.href),
      title = encodeURIComponent(document.title),
      ref = encodeURIComponent(document.referrer);
  img.src = '%s/a.gif?url=' + url + '&t=' + title + '&ref=' + ref;
})();
```

And from client I will run this script from header by:

```
<script async="" src="https://example.com/a.js"> </script>
```

without use staticfile, I think we can use it by urlpattern. But I don't know use for javascript file.

Comment: What exactly do you want here? You want to serve this particular js file in your template? Where is this file coming from?

Comment: I want to generate this javascript and back to response when have request as <script async="" src="https://example.com/a.js"> </script>

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

in views.py:

```
def generatejs(request):
    js_str="""
    (function() {
        var img = new Image,
          url = encodeURIComponent(document.location.href),
          title = encodeURIComponent(document.title),
          ref = encodeURIComponent(document.referrer);
          img.src = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/a.gif?url=' + url + '&t=' + title + '&ref=' + ref;
        })();
    """
    return HttpResponse(js_str)
```

And In urlpatterns, insert:

```
url(r'^gtag/js', collector.generatejs),
```